# When will Unladen Swallow be "done" or "ready" for real use?

Tags: python, unladen-swallow

It looks like Google hasn't updated the results section since the Q4 2009 posting. I've been wondering when it will be put in the Python trunk, and if it's, in any way, production ready.

Also, "We aspire to do no original work" is in the Q4 plan. Did Google bite off more than what they could handle, or does anyone know what the real story is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this, Unladen Swallow will be a part of python 3, it is an officially accepted PEP: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3146/

Comment: Hm... So if that's Unladen Swallow, would regular CPython be Laden Swallow?

Comment: "This PEP proposes the merger of the Unladen Swallow project into CPython's source tree." Unladen Swallow will not be a separate project anymore but rather will be a part of CPython.

Comment: @JAB - that was the original idea from Google.

Comment: PEP 3146 has been withdrawn, and the airspeed velocity of Unladen Swallow appears to now be 0 meters per second.